# passing variable to my default.ctp cakephp

Tags: cakephp, view, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, undefined-index

i am newbie in cakephp ..actually i have two problems .. first one is 
 I am setting variables in AppController in order to use them in 
default.ctp.

```
public function beforeRender(){

    $id = $this->Auth->user('idUser');

    $this->loadModel('Userinfo');
    $data= $this->Userinfo->find('all',array(
        'conditions' => array('Userinfo.User_id' => $id)
    ));

    foreach($data as $d){
        $product_purchase = $d['Userinfo']['product_purchase'];
    }

    $this->set('userinfo',$product_purchase);
}
```

so it is working fine when i use  the variable into my default.ctp layout .. but the problem is when i logout from the the app then it displays this error on my login page

> Undefined variable: product_purchase

What am I doing wrong? 
   by the way i want to mention here is that in my login page i am not using default.ctp well which i think it has nothing to do with dat

the second problem is i want to show specific menu items for the specific user ... so i am doing this in my view page

```
<?php if ($userinfo == 1){ ?> 
  <li><a href="explorer.html" class="shortcut-medias" title="Media">Media</a> </li>
<?php }else{ //nothing }?>
```

value in userinfo is 2 .. but if else isnt working .. it is still displaying the menu

Comment: Hey... Is the code in your application laid out as it is here in this question? If it is, you are breaking your if statement as `//nothing` is commenting out `}`

Comment: @A_Santiago and then tell me what would i do then ?what it should be in the else part ... as i just want to  hide the Media Menu if there is  $userinfo value other then 1

Comment: thankyou i got my problem .. actually i dont have to write the else part ...it works fine without the else part like this                          <li><a href="explorer.html" class="shortcut-medias" title="Media">Media</a> </li>
<?php }?>            and it works .. thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The variable `product_purchase` isn't initialized

If there is no results for the previous find call, the variable `$product_purchase` will not be defined triggering an undefined variable error. This will be the case if there is no logged in user:

```
public function beforeRender(){

    // will be null if there is no user
    $id = $this->Auth->user('idUser');

    // unnecessary find call if there is no user, returning no rows
    $this->loadModel('Userinfo');
    $data= $this->Userinfo->find('all',array(
        'conditions' => array('Userinfo.User_id' => $id)
    ));

    // will not enter this foreach loop as data is empty
    foreach($data as $d){
        $product_purchase = $d['Userinfo']['product_purchase'];
    }

    // $product_purchase is undefined.
    $this->set('userinfo',$product_purchase);
}
```

For the code in the question, just initialize the variable earlier:

```
public function beforeRender(){
    $product_purchase = null;
```

### $producut_purchase may get overwritten

Note that if there is more than one row of data returned for this query:

```
foreach($data as $d){
    $product_purchase = $d['Userinfo']['product_purchase'];
}
```

The `$product_purchase` variable will only contain the value of the *last* row.

If there is only ever one result - use an appropriate method. Don't use `find('all')` - use `find('first')`. Or given the fact that only one field is being retrieved - directly use the `field` method:

```
$product_purchase = $this->Userinfo->field(
    'product_purchase', 
    array('Userinfo.User_id' => $id))
);
```

Comment: thankkkkkkkk you for your detailed answer .. it really helps and solved my problem ..now can you tell how can i resolved the second problem

Comment: i have a problem ... when i used this $product_purchase = $this->Userinfo->field(
    'product_purchase', 
    array('Userinfo.User_id' => $id))
);   i debug this it is returning me true or false .. not the value

Comment: possibly because the field is a `tinyint (1)` (mistake, as that's the same db type as a boolean).

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhh thankyou ... i wax stuck here for almost two hours here because of thhis  ... thank you so much